# PHP - Cookie can't be read after the page is refreshed

Tags: php, setcookie

I know this is a common question, but nothing seems to be working. I have created an age gate to a site and if the user fails they should no longer have access to try again for 30 days and it will just display a "denied" message. If they succeed, they will then be shown the content.

Note: This all happens on a single page/file and after submission, the age is checked and the appropriate cookie is set, then the page is refreshed to display the corresponding content.

I am setting it like this:

```
if($year > 0  && $month > 0 && $day > 0){
    if (time() < strtotime('+18 years', strtotime($submittedDate))) {
        setcookie('age_check', 'denied', time() + (86400 * 30), '/', '.domain.com');
        header('Refresh:0; url=/subpage');
    }else{
        setcookie('age_check', 'validated', time() + (86400 * 30), '/', '.domain.com');
        header('Refresh:0; url=/subpage');
    }
}
```

Then I check using this:

```
if($_COOKIE['age_check'] == 'denied'){
    echo '<h1 class="age-error">Sorry, you may not access this content.</h1>';
    return;
}elseif(!isset($_COOKIE['age_check'])){
    // if it's not present at all, display the age form
}else{
    // it must be set and validated, so show the age gated content
}
```

Just before it refreshes, I am outputting the cookie value for testing and see it output for a split second, but after it refreshes it's empty and just displays the form without any error message or displaying the content, which tells me that `!isset($_COOKIE['age_check'])` is returning true. However, I can see it set in dev tools and it has the correct value.

Can someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($_COOKIE);`?

Comment: @PinkeHelga I did, and it just outputs `array(0) { }`. Even though there are other cookies as well. BUT, again before the refresh it outputs them all

Comment: Have you started a session?

Comment: @fatpenguin yeah, I have `session_start();` at the top of the script

Comment: Check your browser with the dev tools, make sure it receives and stores the cookies.

Comment: @shingo I see it there with the expected value as well. Odd thing is that I can see all the other cookies too but they don't return anything either when checking or outputting

Comment: @shingo So I tested it on a local environment and it works fine. Any idea what on the server's side that could prevent it from not working?

Comment: Then did it send the cookies? Can you share a screenshot? I'm not quite understand what all the other cookies you mean.

Comment: @shingo It did and it shows up in dev tools. Sorry, by all the other cookies, I meant all the miscellaneous ones set by extensions and tracking (twitter, google, etc)

Comment: Have you compared the requests before and after refreshing? Do both have the same age_check cookie? If they have, it's possible that your http service filtered out it.

Comment: @shingo Found out what was going on. I posted the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in case anyone else is having this weird issue, I found the answer.

Seems specific to WP Engine (possibly other hosts as well) and the way that they cache cookies on their end. So I had to contact them and have them add the specific cookie name to an exclusion list under the cache settings. They don't allow you to do this yourself, so you have to contact them to get it added, but at least it was a quick chat.